# Using the same codebase on two sites using Symfony but restricting one site to a very strict area

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have built a site on Symfony 4.4, let's call it `redwidgets.com`. Now as part of this site we have a feature we want to allow other companies to use, however we don't want them to know it's part of `redwidgets.com`.

I have built a page on `www.redwidgets.com/stock-lookup` that I have used a different template for so it's all unbranded etc. And using a ServerAlias in Apache I can see this at `www.genericwidgets.com/stock-loopup`

However I need to block people on `www.genericwidets.com` from going to other sections of the site and seeing it's part of `redwidgets.com`, so I would like it if they try to access the root then they'll just get a generic page.

I did think of maybe there is a way using security.yaml to identify the domain being called and restrict based on that but haven't been able to work out if that's possible.

I did think of just hosting this page in a separate site, but I am very unsure how the same database can be shared between the sites, would you have to duplicate Entities and code etc, that would sound very annoying. It can't just be separate as `redwidgets.com` makes large use of the relevant entities.

Currently using Symfony 4.4, Apache 2.4

Comment: You can [restrict routes to certain subdomains](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing).

Comment: Interesting, so I could just have those Controllers I need reply to stock.genericwidgets.com that could work! Thanks, had completely overlooked that when researching